# Serialize a generic class (without the need of a XML helper class)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, generics, xml-serialization

I have a question regarding the serialization of a generic class.

Because I want to use a generic class for all my Configuration (which gets serialized as an XML) I have written the following class:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Reflection.Assembly

<Serializable()> _
Public Class GenericConfig(Of T)
    Public Sub WriteToFile(ByVal FileName As String)
        ConfigVersion = ProgrammVersion.ToString
        Dim XmlFile As FileStream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create)
        Dim serialize As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(GenericConfig(Of T)), New Type() {GetType(GenericConfig(Of T))})
        serialize.Serialize(XmlFile, Me)
        XmlFile.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ReadFromFile(ByVal FileName As String) As GenericConfig(Of T)
        Dim XmlFile As FileStream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open)
        Dim serialize As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(GenericConfig(Of T)))
        ReadFromFile = serialize.Deserialize(XmlFile)
        XmlFile.Close()
        Return ReadFromFile
    End Function

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property ConfigFileName() As String
        Get
            Return GetExecutingAssembly.Location.Substring(0, GetExecutingAssembly.Location.Length - 4) & ".Config.xml"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class ToolConfig
    Inherits GenericConfig(Of ToolConfig)

    Public Property Key1 As String = "Value 1"
End Class
```

The problem I have is that I cannot serialize it because of the following error at line

```
serialize.Serialize(XmlFile, Me)
```

{"The type GenericConfigClass.ToolConfig was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."}

I have googled and found a lot of article which relate to that error if you use XMLSerializer on derived classes. I am not doing that here. I am using it on a generic class.

Is there a way other than creating an XML helper class like this fellow here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35925/Generic-XML-Serialization-Methods

Thanks,
Wolfgang

**Update:**
This is how I call it (short example)

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmMain
    Dim Config As ToolConfig

    Private Sub btnConfigInit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfigInit.Click
        '----------------- read config file  -----------------
        If File.Exists(ToolConfig.ConfigFileName) Then
            Config = ToolConfig.ReadFromFile(ToolConfig.ConfigFileName)
        Else
            Config = New ToolConfig
        End If
        Config.WriteToFile(ToolConfig.ConfigFileName)

        MsgBox(Config.Key1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please post the code of the class you're trying to serialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *are* using a derived class: `ToolConfig`.  Make it known via `XmlInclude` and you should be fine:

Add `<XmlInclude(GetType(ToolConfig))>` to `GenericConfig`.

Another solution should be to simply use `Me.GetType()` instead of `GetType(GenericConfig(Of T))` when creating the `XmlSerializer` instance:

```
Dim serialize As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(Me.GetType())
```

To be able to successfully deserialize, you will have to make the shared `ReadFromFile` method either an instance method or make it generic.

---

If you want to keep that deserializing method shared, you can do it like this:

```
Public Class GenericConfig ' <- No (Of T) here! But in the line below.
    Public Shared Function ReadFromFile(Of T)(ByVal FileName As String) As T
        Dim XmlFile As FileStream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open)
        Dim serialize As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
        ReadFromFile = serialize.Deserialize(XmlFile)
        XmlFile.Close()
        Return ReadFromFile
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
GenericConfig.ReadFromFile(Of ToolConfig)(filename)
```

Comment: ToolConfig is just an example. This should be a generic class. If I specfy the Type "ToolConfig" it wont be generic anymore.

Before I modified my config class here to be generic the Type Name in WriteToFile were hardcoded. Because I am using this in my places now I would like it to be generic.

Comment: @wolfixx: I don't understand your comment, but you don't seem to understand the problem either. `GenericConfig.WriteToFile` passes `Me` to the `Serialize` method. Now, if you have an instance of `ToolConfig` and call `WriteToFile` on it, you are trying to serialize an object of type `ToolConfig` - which is an unknown derived type.

Comment: I tried that already. I put '<XmlInclude(GetType(ToolConfig))> _' in front of the ToolConfig Class definition but it didn't help.
<br>
I can't add it the the class GenericConfig unfortunately. If I do I get a compile error saying that XMLInclude doesn't allow generic parameters.

Comment: @wolfixx: Please see update. You need to add XmlInclude for ToolConfig to GenericConfig. That shouldn't give any errors about generic parameters, because ToolConfig doesn't have any.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for trying to help. I really appreciate it. The reason why I don't want to do that is that GenericConfig would not be generic anymore. I want to put GenericConfig into a diffeent namespace / dll and use if for later projects. Today it's ToolsConfig, tomorrow it might be PlaneConfig or WorldConfig (just some examples :-) I don't want to recompile the base class everytime I reuse that code. Otherwise I have no advantgae to what I am doing at the moment (I have a non generic class version which I copy to every project I do).

Comment: @wolfixx: I understand your concerns, I find it a strange requirement, too, to have to register the derived classes with their base class. But you are lucky, I just realized that there is a much simpler solution in your case. Please see update.

Comment: Thank you Daniel !!!!  That's the solution. Me.GetType() does the trick. And I made ReadFromFile an instance method for the time being. Maybe one day I find a way to convert it to a shared function again.

Comment: @WolfgangReh: You can make it a shared method, please see update. I am no VB guy, so I might have screwed up the syntax a bit.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's even better. I got my shared function again ;-)